# Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: c#, listview, selecteditem

I realize this may look like a duplicate question (I've seen many other questions asking about this error), however I cannot find an answer which explains the issue I'm having. The error is provoked by a call to

```
invList.SelectedItems[0].Text //invList is a ListView
```

From what I've read, the error when provoked by this instruction is indicative of attempted access to an empty list (or array?) of selected items in the ListView. However, the ListView I am attempting to access is populated with items at the time of the instruction's execution. Here are the methods in which I issue this instruction:

Method #1: deleteItem

```
public bool deleteItem()
    {
        if (invList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) //if no item selected...
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: No item selected", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
                "Are you sure you want to delete item: " + invList.SelectedItems[0].Text + "?",
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemRecords.Count; i++)
                {
                    if ((itemRecords[i].id.ToString() == invList.SelectedItems[0].Text) && (itemRecords[i].practice == clinicName))
                    {
                        itemRecords.Remove(itemRecords[i]);
                        listRefresh();
                    }
                }
                return true; //return true to indicate that data has been edited
            }
            return false; // return false to indicate that nothing has changed
        }
    }
```

Method #2: updateItem

```
 public bool updateItem()
    {
        if (invList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) //if no item selected
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: No item selected", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemRecords.Count; i++)
            {
                //if id == the id of the selected item
                if((itemRecords[i].id.ToString() == invList.SelectedItems[0].Text) && (itemRecords[i].practice == this.Text))
                {
                    ItemAddition itemAddition = new ItemAddition(itemRecords, itemRecords[i], this);
                    itemAddition.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

listRefresh:

```
       public void listRefresh()
    {
        invList.Items.Clear();
        loadItems();
    }
```

loadItems:

```
        private void loadItems()
    {
        foreach (Record r in itemRecords)
        {
            if (r.practice == clinicName)
                invList.Items.Add(r.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The error is invoked when the first method is called, but NOT when the second method is called. This inconsistency is the reason for my confusion. Is there some reason this error would only occur in the first method?

Comment: Can you add code of listRefresh method?

Comment: @Damith Sure, I've added it.

Comment: try to modify `for (int i = 0; i < itemRecords.Count-1; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move refreshing method after remove items. If you move item and rebind, then you will lost selection.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < itemRecords.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((itemRecords[i].id.ToString() == invList.SelectedItems[0].Text) && (itemRecords[i].practice == clinicName))
        {
            itemRecords.Remove(itemRecords[i]);
            //listRefresh();
        }
    }

listRefresh();                
return true;
```

Comment: I had just found a rough solution to my problem when I saw your answer. This is exactly what was wrong. Thank you very much for your help.